# Unexpected end on a ruby code that seems right

Tags: ruby

I was on my path to enlightment on ruby koans, but a imponent obstacle have presented itself before me. In the about_scoring_project I'm receveing some syntax errors on lines where I have put `end` to previous 
`for`.

```
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
: C:/Users/Psico/Downloads/rubykoans/koans/about_scoring_project.rb:62: syntax error, unexpected `end' (SyntaxError)
  end
  ^~~
C:/Users/Psico/Downloads/rubykoans/koans/about_scoring_project.rb:74: syntax error, unexpected `end'
  end
```

I've tried to delete those ends, but then i receive a expecting "end" error.

My code is as follows:

```
class DiceError < StandardError
end


def score(dice)
  # You need to write this method
  totalScore = 0
  numbers = {1 => 0, 2 => 0, 3 => 0, 4 => 0, 5 => 0, 6 => 0}
  for elem in dice
    unless (elem >= 1 && elem <= 6)
      raise DiceError, "#{elem} is not a number of a six faced dice"
    end

    numbers[elem] += 1

  end

  valuesArray = numbers.values
  indexCounter = 0

  for elem in valuesArray   ## conta pontos de triplas #TODO passar para uma função separada 
    if elem >= 3
      if indexCounter == 0
        totalScore += 1000
      else
        totalScore += 100 * (indexCounter + 1)
      end
      valuesArray[indexCounter] = elem - 3
    end
    indexCounter++
  end

  indexCounter = 0 #zera o contador
  singlesPoints = Hash.new(0)
  singlesPoints[0] = 100
  singlesPoints[4] = 50
  for elem in valuesArray
    if elem > 0
      totalScore += singlesPoints[indexCounter] * elem
    end
    valuesArray[indexCounter] = 0 #garante que no fim o vetor de valores seja todo igual a 0
    indexCounter++
  end

  puts("#{numbers}") 
  return totalScore
end
```

Comment: Ruby doesn't have a post-increment operator so `indexCounter++` can trigger very confusing problems when Ruby attempts to parse it. Change those to `indexCounter += 1` first.

Comment: The Rubyist will not generally use `for`, and will instead use built-in iterators like `array.each { |element| ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

You have an `end` on the second line of your code under `class DiceError < StandardError`

This was probably automatically put there when you started writing the class. Try moving it to the last line (after `end`):

```
  puts("#{numbers}") 
    return totalScore
  end
end
```

Hope this helps :)